# MySQL Query. How do I showed associated SellerID

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Let's say we have 2 tables, sellers and property.
We want the Property with the lowest price and the associated seller ID.

So I want the output to look something like

```
Lowest_Price____Seller_ID

1000.00_________12
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT MIN(Price)AS Lowest_Price,Seller_ID
FROM Property;
```

I'm getting the lowest price like i wanted, but its not giving me the seller id associated to that property. I know I'm missing a function, but i'm not sure which to use.

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT MIN(Price) AS Lowest_Price, Seller_ID
FROM Property
GROUP BY Seller_ID
ORDER BY MIN(Price)
LIMIT 1;
```